# Get Discord ping message/Windows 10 popup notification

Tags: python, discord

Assuming that someone `@everyone` or `@Ping Role` on one of my Discord server. There will be a pop-up for Windows 10 for the ping. Are there any way to get that ping message using Python and copy it to clipboard?

Comment: Are you talking about discord.py?

Comment: No, my question doesn't have anything to do with discord.py, I just wanna get the message in Discord notification and copy to clipboard

Answer (score 0):

You can click on [that icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZm1x.png) in the discord app (on the top-right corner)